# I am unable to run nodejs project

Tags: node.js

I am unable to run node Project. it showing error when I run node minify.js

[image]

Comment: did you try to  npm install -g cleancss ?

Comment: run npm install and then run the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install Jvm and npm minify.js then it works